# MYSQL - JOIN matching rows after group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using group by on a SELECT statement so instead of getting 50 rows, I get 3 because there are no unique ids to join them together by.

Now, I need to use these 3 rows with a unique ID to get ALL rows from another table where the id matches.

and THEN I need to use each of these rows and join them with another table if a date is between two dates.

```
SELECT * FROM dogs

JOIN dogs_owners ON dogs_owners.acc_number = dogs_owners.account

WHERE dogs.project_id = 5000

AND dogs_owners.type = "cute"

GROUP BY dogs_owners.account
```

This now gives me 3 rows instead of the 100+ that matches.

Now, I need to use the dogs_owners.account value and get ALL matching rows from another table.

Something like JOIN another_table ON another_table.account = dogs_owners.account

However, this just gives me the same 3 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM dogs

JOIN dogs_owners ON dogs_owners.acc_number = dogs_owners.account

JOIN support_info_row ON support_info_row.account =  dog_owners.acc_number

WHERE dogs.project_id = 5000

AND dogs_owners.type = "cute"

GROUP BY dogs_owners.account
```

This only gives me 3 rows still, instead of the 50+ rows.

After this I would also need to to join these 50+ rows with another table.

```
SELECT * FROM dogs

JOIN dogs_owners ON dogs_owners.acc_number = dogs_owners.account

JOIN support_info_row ON support_info_row.account =  dog_owners.acc_number
 
JOIN support_info ON support_info.row_id = support_info_row.id AND support_info_row.date BETWEEN day1 AND day2

WHERE dogs.project_id = 5000

AND dogs_owners.type = "cute"

GROUP BY dogs_owners.account
```

Comment: In some versions of sql you would not be able to use a group by without any aggregation and you should follow this precept.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: The queries are malformed and will return unpredictable results. All column not listed in the `GROUP BY` clause need to be aggregated (`SUM()`, `MAX()`, etc.)

Comment: I've managed to find the solution to my issue.

I had to do a few subqueries instead :) Now it works, live and learn